# Average values in a csv file to the nearest whole number in R

Tags: r

I have a csv file containing information on available beds in UK hospitals. The download link for the file is here:

[CSV File Download](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/georgebt-f1af8.appspot.com/o/data.csv?alt=media&token=29e37e44-8cab-4199-80b0-3f0ff2081102)

The file is a combination of characters and integers so, with my very limited knowledge of R, It doesn't seem strait-forward for me to use ceiling() or floor() to round up.

The data I want to round up is all of these:

[Integers to Round](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fMw8.png)

Basically any number which is not whole within this file I want to be made a whole number.

So far all I have done is read the file into R like so:

```
NHS_Data <- read.csv(file="data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

Which looks like this:

[CSV File in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oerSW.png)

Now I'm afraid I'm stuck - Can anybody help?

Many thanks,
George

Comment: Honestly, I think you should start with *An Introduction to R* or some of the other resources in the [R tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info). You need to clean your data - get it in a nice data frame where the column classes reflect the values. Looking at your data picture you have mixed types within columns (dates on one row, number on another, blanks on another), so don't worry about rounding yet, just try to get your data into shape where the numbers are `numeric`, the dates are `Date`, the blanks are `NA`, column headers are meaningful...

Comment: Ahh okay I had a feeling I may have to do that.. The file is in a state I know its how it was given to me. I will give it a tidy up and push on from there

Comment: But try some stuff out. Read questions on Stack Overflow about importing and manipulating data. Try some stuff. Share some attempts. From your question it's not clear if you know really what a data frame is, how to convert columns, use `if` statements, etc. Which makes it very hard to help you in an effective way.

Comment: And general advice for SO - don't post images of data. A small copy/pasteable bit of data is **much** more useful than a picture of a data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bit more going on in the `CSV` than just rounding up. R dislikes having numbers in the column names and dashes `-`. So, it will likely bring them in as `"X.2009.10"` or something similar.

You will need to be aware of this.

Based on what you have above you would start as you did:

```
NHS_Data <- read.csv(file="data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

Then you will identify the column you want to raise or lower and wrap it in `ceiling` or `floor` like so:

```
NHS_Data$X.2009.10 <- floor(NHS_Data$X.2009.10)
```

This tells it to save into the data frame `NHS_Data` at the location of the column `X.2009.10` each row of `X.2009.10` at the largest whole integer below your floating number in the same cell.

Comment: This works! Thanks so much! I will still take the advice of Gregor though and clean up my CSV file

Comment: You definitely should. There are good sources, like datacamp.com which are affordable and make it easy, as well! Have fun...